# How can I disable image dragging on a <picture> element with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am unable to disable image dragging when using a `<picture>` element. I have used this in the past with an `<img>` element with success. I'm not sure why it doesn't work with `<picture>`.

HTML Code:

```
<picture class="thumb">
<source class="nodrag" srcset="image.webp" type="image/webp">
<source class="nodrag" srcset="image.gif" type="image/gif">
<img class="thumb" src="image.gif">
</picture>
```

My Javascript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('thumb').ondragstart = function () { return false; };
document.getElementsByClassName('nodrag').ondragstart = function () { return false; };
```

The above did not work. Is there another way I can disable dragging of a  element to prevent users from dragging to save the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it will work for your use-case but have you tried the HTML [draggable attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/draggable)?

```
<img class="thumb" src="image.gif" draggable="false">
```

Comment: That works! I wonder why my more complex solution didn't work but this did haha.

Comment: Based on the code provided I cannot tell why your picture element is draggable to begin with (maybe something in your css that specifies this?) - ondragstart is an event that is fired when you move a draggable element. Your function () {return false;}; will not register unless you have created a function that makes picture draggable and you want to prevent it from executing. - If you want to go about it your way, try logging your function and see what is happening. Or simply set draggable="false" on the element. - If I helped please feel free to mark correct :)